Node.js SSL Certificate Error When Making HTTPS Requests to OpenAI API
I'm developing a Node.js application that makes API requests to OpenAI using the openai npm package. However, I'm encountering an SSL certificate error when attempting to connect to the API. Below is the error message I receive:
Error: APIConnectionError: Connection error.
    at OpenAI.makeRequest (node_modules/openai/core.js:292:19)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
FetchError: request to https://api.openai.com/v1/chat/completions failed, reason: unable to get local issuer certificate


I've tried the following solutions, but none have resolved the issue:

Setting the environment variable NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED=0 to bypass TLS/SSL certificate                     validation (not suitable for production).
Using a custom https agent in the code with rejectUnauthorized: false to disable SSL/TLS verification for requests.

Here is a snippet of my code using the custom https agent:
const OpenAI = require("openai");
const https = require("https");

const agent = new https.Agent({  
  rejectUnauthorized: false
});

const openai = new OpenAI({
    apiKey: process.env.OPENAI_API_KEY,
    agent
});

async function getCompletion() {
    try {
        const chatCompletion = await openai.chat.completions.create({
            messages: [{ role: "user", content: "Say this is a test" }],
            model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
        });
        console.log(chatCompletion);
    } catch (error) {
        console.error("Error:", error);
    }
}

getCompletion();


Despite these attempts, I continue to get the SSL certificate error. Here's my setup:
Node.js version: 14.17.0
Operating System: Windows 10
Could this issue be related to my Node.js configuration, network environment, or something else? How can I resolve this error without compromising security? Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Context
A rough context on SSL requests: A server will present a chain of signed SSL certificates to the client. The client will validate that this chain of certificates is trusted by comparing it against its own certificate store, looking for the CA root certificate that matches the chain.
Problem
The error you saw is a common / generic one which typically indicates that your application could not find a matching certificate in its own store, and so cannot verify the certificate of the server.
Node.js doesn't have a store per-se. By default, it will use a hard-coded list of root certificates which are updated between node versions.
That OpenAI endpoint given currently uses "GTS Root R1" as it's root CA certificate. This certificate was added / updated in node 18, which explains why you aren't able to verify it running node 14.
Solution

Update nodeJS. Ideally to LTS (currently v20.12.2), but at least to node 18 to obtain the updated certificate.
Store and reference the CA cert manually. Download the certificate and reference it in your run time options (See: How to add custom certificate authority (CA) to nodejs). There may also be a way to configure this with the https module directly, but I'm not sure.


Beg to differ. Although GTS Root R1 is recent and not trusted everywhere yet, that server also sends a bridge to GlobalSign Root CA which is long-established and IS accepted in node 14 (on my systems, both native-Windows and docker-on-ubuntu). Possibly OP's traffic is being intercepted (especially likely on Windows) but even if so I'm surpised the envvar for REJECT doesn't work, unless the 'openai'code is explicitly being picky.

Yep, traffic being intercepted is something that is worrying to suggest but if it's the case that there's still a valid root CA then it does narrow down what could be wrong quite significantly! Thanks for your input
